# horizontally center two divs

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I have two  that I need horizontally centered to each other, wrapped in a single div. can you please explain what I am doing wrong?

My HTML

```
    <div id="center">
    <div id="logo"><img src="images/blackcat_logo.png" width="200px"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>SHOP</li>
            <li>ARTIST</li>
            <li>SERVICES</li>
            <li>FAQs</li>
            <li>CONTACT</li>
        </ul>    
    </nav>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
header{
   height:500px;
   width:auto;
   background-image:url(images/headerphoto.png);
   text-align:center;
}

#center{
   width:960px;
   margin:auto;
   overflow:hidden;
   display:inline-block;
}

#logo{
   float:left;
   display:inline-block;
}

nav{
   float:right;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: There is no header element in your HTML, did you mean to include one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the float from #logo and nav. Then set your #center div to text-align:center;

```
#center {
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting the divs stacked on top of each other, and then centered. Im looking to have the logo left, nav right and the two centered horizontally. Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LFQt2 Is this what you are seeing? I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: here is what i've got. http://danielmdesigns.com/blackcattattoo/index.html -- everything aligns top or bottom. i'd like to align both the logo and nav to the middle

Comment: Ok maybe you just wrote it wrong, are you sure you're not looking to align it "vertically" centered instead of horizontally?

If you are here's what you can do:

Set a line height of 72px on your ul.

Comment: wow. so sorry! yes. that is exactly what i was looking for. sorry for wasting your precious time. thank you so much!!!

Comment: Haha no problem. You can also use a padding-top or a margin -top on the menu to achieve the same effect. If you could mark the question as resolved just incase somebody else comes along with the same issue that would be great, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#center {
  text-align:center;
}
#logo, nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

The above code works for me http://www.cssdesk.com/QKNNj .
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *full* CSS should be:

```
#center {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
}
```